# How to compile using EiffelStudio? VD43 Precompiled file is missing or unreadable (...)/driver.exe - External C compilation failed

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-19.12

After installing EiffelStudio I can't compile and run any project because I always get VD43 warning and C Compiler Error.

```
2   VD43    Precompiled file is missing or unreadable. File 'c:\users\username\documents\eiffel user files\19.05\precomp\spec\win64\EIFGENs\base-scoop-safe\W_code\msc_vc140\driver.exe'.   

        
1   C Compiler Error    Please review the External Compilation output of the Outputs Tool.              
    Error code: C Compiler Error

Error: External C/C++ compilation failed.
What to do: Check the external C/C++ compilation for details.

Please review the External Compilation output of the Outputs Tool.
```

I found this page: https://www.eiffel.org/doc/version/trunk/faq/FAQ. The key ISE_C_COMPILER must be additionally defined in order for EiffelStudio to work at all. **But how does one "Tell EiffelStudio to use Visual Studio 2017-compatible libraries"?** I tried setting it as an environment variable, and changing the compile_library.bat and esvars.bat, so that in every place it's `set ISE_C_COMPILER=msc_vc140`. I also added variable ISE_C_COMPILER - msc_vc140 on the EiffelStudio GUI, under Project->Project Settings->Target:project->Advanced->Variables

I deleted all the projects and the precomp folder. I ran `espawn -l` just to verify that I have the good c++ compiler:

```
Available C/C++ compilers:

   VC160:  Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 VC++ (19.0)
   VC150:  Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 VC++ (15.0)
```

To me it seems that I installed everything and I set every variable but it still gives me the same warning and error.

Comment: Have you removed `...\precomp\spec\win64\EIFGENs` as mentioned in the FAQ before recompiling the project? Also, there were reports when command-line tools like `nmake`, `cl` and `link` were not installed with Visual Studio. In that case you may need to re-run Visual Studio installation to install them.

Comment: Yes, I removed the entire precomp folder. The issue disappeared when I uninstalled the 19.05 version and installed the 20.11 version - using the exact same settings, it works, on 19.05 it still won't work.

Comment: For an unknown reason EiffelStudio is sometimes unable to properly setup paths to Visual Studio (it depends on Visual Studio installation options). Also, old EiffelStudio versions do not support new Visual Studio versions. However, it's still possible to setup the environment manually: 1) launch the command line prompt; 2) run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64` (or similar, depending on your version of Visual Studio); 3) make sure `ISE_C_COMPILER` is properly set; 4) start EiffelStudio from this command line by `...\estudio`.